# Dominicus = church?

Tags: christianity

I'm puzzled by the following text referring to St. Anthony of Egypt (second reading [here](https://universalis.com/L/americas/20220117/readings.htm)), written by St. Athanasius in the 4th century:

> Sex autem nondum exáctis ménsibus a paréntum éxitu, cum de more **ad Domínicum** procéderet,

The page translate it as "Not six months after his parents’ death, as he was on his way **to church** for his usual visit"

Similarly, we have:

> egréssus quamprímum **ex Domínico**

Corresponding to "Immediately he left **the church**"

And then we read:

> Rursus **in Domínicum** ingréssus

Which is translated as "The next time he went **to church**".

So, judging by declensions, there seems to be a word "Dominicus" meaning church. Yet, cannot find reference to this meaning in online Latin dictionaries. The expression is not widely used elsewhere, it seems.

Is this very idiomatic and context-dependent? Or is there in fact such meaning more broadly speaking?

Comment: Perhaps helpful: in the original Greek, "ad Dominicum" is "εἰς τὸ Κυριακόν."

Comment: @brianpck by the original you mean Athanasius' (PG) text? Right. So in Ancient Greek [it did](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CF%85%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%BA%CF%8C%CE%BD) mean church. In other word, the "problem" is the literal translation (and not idiomatic) from Ancient Greek to Latin. Or perhaps a brave Latinist who wanted to introduce the idiom to Latin, without success. The English one corrected the translation.

Comment: I'll post an answer later, but it makes sense in Latin, too. *Dominicum* would be roughly "something pertaining to *dominus*,' but in the neuter it often is tied to places. In English, it would be like saying, "house of the Lord." Not the normal word for 'church', but it's not a leap, either.

Comment: @luchonacho Yep, I was talking about Athanasius's text. The parallel translation in the *PG* also uses "Dominicum." I thought it would be helpful, but I wasn't suggesting the Latin term was incorrect or unidiomatic!

Comment: Here is an entry for it in a few Latin dictionaries including L&S and DMLBS: https://logeion.uchicago.edu/dominicus. It seems to not mean church exactly, but "belonging to lord," "Lord's Day" (aka Sunday) when with *dies*, and "divine."

Answer (score 3):

Quoniam "Dominicus" interdum ad "diem" refert (dies Domini), fortasse attinet ad missam istius diei, quem Romani diem Solis appellabant. Attamen mirum est, quod masculini generis est, nam dies est Dominica /Domenica, missa quoque, cena, quam Lewis and Short dictionarium memorat, item...

Comment: At neque 'in *diem* ingredī' potest neque 'ex *missā* ēgredī' - quae praetereā utraque fēminīnī generis sunt. Hīc manufestē aedēs significantur, quod et interpretātiō anglica probat, et praesertim ipsum illud Graecum 'το Κυριακόν' unde Latīnē versum est.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian "missa" is definitely used in Christian Latin as an event occurring in a place, which one could enter or exit. From the Concilia Galliae: "Ut populus ante benedictionem sacerdotis de missa non egrediatur". From the Vita S. Gregorii: "[eum] de Missa nondum finita violentis manibus abstraxerunt"

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian though, rereading your comment, I think you meant only that such an expression (ex missa egredi) is impossible here, not in general. So, disregard my previous comment, I suppose.

Comment: @Kingshorsey The crucial difference here is that *ex* 'out of' is used with the **space-as-container** metaphor while *dē* 'down/away from' doesn't conceive of the Mass as a space at all, but as you say, an event. Thus you can drag someone away from a Mass, but hardly out of it. It's true that *Dominicum* [is used both](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/dominicum) of the place and of the service - I'm using the choice of preposition as a means to decide which it is.